# HTML problems with TinyMCE

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I use TinyMCE for posting blog posts. Now i want to post the **exact** following in plain text, not as HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Title goes here</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I switch to HTML only, code is converted to (as it should do, I guess?):

```
<p>&lt;ul&gt;<br />&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="#"&gt;Title goes here&lt;/li&gt;<br />&lt;/ul&gt;</p>
```

However, when I publish the blog post, the result is:

- [Title goes here](http://example.com)

Just to be clear: it won't show as WYSIWYG, but as a HTML execution.

**tinyMCE.init**
http://jsfiddle.net/rmGuB/

Any solution and ideas would be very helpful.

PHP is used for the blog post execution.

Comment: Firstly `<link>` should be `</li>`. TinyMCE works by posting html, so Im not really sure what the problem is.. can you post your PHP?

Comment: @chriz Oops, that's just a hasty careless mistake!

Answer (score 1):

You can completely switch off the HTML parsing in tiny MCE, but then it would be pretty useless having it there.  Your markup isn't valid (you're closing an [li] element with a [/link].  That's not just invalid XHTML, it's invalid HTML.  Is it a typo, or are you trying to store the invalid content for a reason?  May be there's a better way to handle the content if you can provide a bit more info.